# how to object initialize in PHP and then what function do I make within the class which runs automatically?

Tags: php, oop, object

hi i forgot the code which in a sample class you have to add so that it runs automatically?

is it wakeup or something?

like so:

```
class something {
 function automaticxxx_something_which_runs when class is created()
 {
 }
}

$s = new something();
```

-what do i create in the class file so that something runs already after the class is initialized?

i forgot how to name the function name so that it would call it automatically the first function.

Comment: I may be nitpicking - but isn't this a classic case of 'read the documentation' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're after a constructor.  In PHP4 the method has the same name as the class

```
class Foobar
{
    function Foobar()
    {
        echo "Hello World!\n";
    }
}

new Foobar()
```

In PHP5 the above method still works, but the correct way is to use the __construct() method

```
class Foobar
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo "Hello World!\n";
    }
}

new Foobar();
```

Comment: As of PHP 5.3.3 the first method no longer works as a constructor function.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a constructor that works in both versions ( although, you should not be coding for php4 as its well past its end-of-life now )

```
class Foobar
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo "Hello World!\n";
    }
    function Foobar() 
    {
        return $this->__construct();  
    }
}
```

If you are coding for **Just** php5 you should get into the habit of specifying visibility explicitly,

```
class Foobar 
{
    public function __construct() 
    { 
    }
}
```

(visibility definers didn't exist back in php4)

Should do the trick, with a minor performance loss under php4.